# reportlab.platypus - rendering template with a right aligned image in the template header as background

Tags: python, django, pdf-generation, django-views, reportlab

i'm tryng to use Reportlab to output an invoice on a simple Django app. it seems quite difficult to do simple things like this. here's my code:

```
def print_pdf(fattura, soggetto, buffer=None):

import time
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_LEFT, TA_CENTER, TA_RIGHT, TA_JUSTIFY
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, Image, ParagraphAndImage
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle, getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib.units import inch

static_files_dir_path = settings.SITE_ROOT+'/'+settings.CURRENT_APP_NAME+settings.STATIC_URL+'user/images/';
img_file = 'Logo_effetti.jpg'
img_height = 75
img_width = 99

str_data_fatt = (fattura.data).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
fattura_file_name = str('fattura_'+str_data_fatt+'_'+str(fattura.soggetto)+'.pdf')

img = Image(static_files_dir_path+img_file, img_width, img_height)

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
normalStyle = styles["Normal"]

nfattura_ptext = 'numero fattura: '+str(fattura.numerofattura)

if buffer:
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer, pagesize=letter)
else:
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(fattura_file_name, pagesize=letter)
elems = []

intestazione_studio_ptext = 'Studio AAA<br/>Via XXX 99<br/> 20202 DDDDDDD'
prestazioni = []

elems.append(Paragraph(intestazione_studio_ptext, styles["Normal"]))
elems.append(Spacer(1,12))
elems.append(Spacer(1,12))
elems.append(Spacer(1,12))

elems.append(Paragraph(nfattura_ptext, styles["Normal"]))
cliente_ptext = soggetto.nome+" "+soggetto.cognome+"<br/>"+soggetto.indirizzo+", "+soggetto.cap+" "+soggetto.citta+"<br/>C.F.: "+soggetto.codfisc
if(soggetto.is_privato):
    cliente_ptext += "P.IVA: "+soggetto.piva

prezzo = Prezzo.objects.get(pk=1)

if fattura.riabmot > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'Rieducazione motoria','qta': fattura.riabmot,'p_unit': prezzo.riabmot,
                        'p_finale': fattura.riabmot * prezzo.riabmot,'id':'riabmot'})
if fattura.riabacq > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'Riabilitazione in acqua','qta': fattura.riabacq,'p_unit': prezzo.riabacq,
                        'p_finale': fattura.riabacq * prezzo.riabacq,'id':'riabacq'})
if fattura.riabdom > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'Riabilitazione domiciliare','qta': fattura.riabdom,'p_unit': prezzo.riabdom,
                        'p_finale':fattura.riabdom * prezzo.riabdom,'id':'riabdom'})
if fattura.osteo > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'Osteopatia','qta': fattura.osteo,'p_unit': prezzo.osteo,
                        'p_finale':fattura.osteo * prezzo.osteo,'id':'osteo'})
if fattura.masso > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'Massoterapia','qta': fattura.masso,'p_unit': prezzo.masso,
                        'p_finale':fattura.masso * prezzo.masso,'id':'masso'})
if fattura.diate > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'Diatermia','qta': fattura.diate,'p_unit': prezzo.diate,
                             'p_finale':fattura.diate * prezzo.diate,'id':'diate'})
if fattura.laser > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'Laserterapia','qta': fattura.laser,'p_unit': prezzo.laser,
                            'p_finale':fattura.laser * prezzo.laser,'id':'laser'})
if fattura.usman > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'US Manuale','qta': fattura.usman,'p_unit': prezzo.usman,
                            'p_finale':fattura.usman * prezzo.usman,'id':'usman'})
if fattura.usacq > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'US in acqua','qta': fattura.usacq,'p_unit': prezzo.usacq,
                            'p_finale':fattura.usacq * prezzo.usacq,'id':'usacq'})
if fattura.tens > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'TENS','qta': fattura.tens,'p_unit': prezzo.tens,
                            'p_finale':fattura.tens * prezzo.tens,'id':'usacq'})
if fattura.ets > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'Elettroterapia stimolante','qta': fattura.ets,'p_unit': prezzo.ets,
                             'p_finale': fattura.ets * prezzo.ets,'id':'ets'})
if fattura.magneto > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'Magnetoterapia','qta': fattura.magneto,'p_unit': prezzo.magneto,
                            'p_finale':fattura.magneto * prezzo.magneto,'id':'magneto'})
if fattura.iono > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'Ionoforesi','qta': fattura.iono,'p_unit': prezzo.iono,
                            'p_finale':fattura.iono * prezzo.iono,'id':'iono'})

totale = 0
totale += fattura.diate * prezzo.diate
totale += fattura.ets * prezzo.ets
totale += fattura.iono * prezzo.iono
totale += fattura.tens * prezzo.tens
totale += fattura.laser * prezzo.laser
totale += fattura.magneto * prezzo.magneto
totale += fattura.masso * prezzo.masso
totale += fattura.usacq * prezzo.usacq
totale += fattura.usman * prezzo.usman
totale += fattura.osteo * prezzo.osteo
totale += fattura.riabacq * prezzo.riabacq
totale += fattura.riabdom * prezzo.riabdom
totale += fattura.riabmot * prezzo.riabmot

prestazioni_instestazione_ptext = "Prestazione     N.Sedute     Pr. unitario (euro)     Pr. finale (euro)"
elems.append(Paragraph(prestazioni_instestazione_ptext, styles["Normal"]))
elems.append(Spacer(1,12))
for p in prestazioni:
    prestazione_ptext = p['nome']+"     "+str(p['qta'])+"     "+str(p['p_unit'])+"     "+str(p['p_finale'])
    elems.append(Paragraph(prestazione_ptext, styles["Normal"]))


elems.append(Spacer(1,12))
elems.append(Spacer(1,12))
totale_ptext = "Importo totale: "+str(totale)+" euro"
elems.append(Paragraph(totale_ptext, styles["Normal"]))

doc.build(elems);
return buffer;
```

with this code, my header image is always rendered on page center. i want to insert it on the right (like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np6ix.png) ) or even better having image on the right and text on the left. i've tried in many ways (setting the hAlign or oAlign propetry of img, inserting image in a ParagraphAndImage flowable) but always i got errors or the same alignment.
what is the right way?

i've tried to look at Reportlab documentation but seems not so clear to me and poor of code snippets.

tnx to everyone,

LuKe

---

thanks for your reply. i've modified the code by this way:

```
def print_fatt_pdf(fattura, soggetto, buffer=None):

import time
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_LEFT, TA_CENTER, TA_RIGHT, TA_JUSTIFY
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer
from reportlab.platypus.frames import Frame
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle, getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib.units import inch, cm
from PIL import Image
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas

static_files_dir_path = settings.SITE_ROOT+'/'+settings.CURRENT_APP_NAME+settings.STATIC_URL+'user/images/';
img_file = 'Logo_effetti.jpg'
img_height = 75
img_width = 98
elems = []


str_data_fatt = (fattura.data).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
fattura_file_name = str('fattura_'+str_data_fatt+'_'+str(fattura.soggetto)+'.pdf')
print 'fattura_file_name',fattura_file_name

f = Frame(1.5*cm, 1.5*cm, 6*inch, 9*inch)
p = Canvas(buffer);

# adding flowables
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
normalStyle = styles["Normal"]

nfattura_ptext = 'numero fattura: '+str(fattura.numerofattura)
intestazione_studio_ptext = 'Studio Fisiodel<br/>Via Sant\'Isaia 99<br/>20012 Mantegazza di Vanzago (MI)'
print 'intestazione_studio_ptext type: ',type(intestazione_studio_ptext)
elems.append(Paragraph(intestazione_studio_ptext, normalStyle))
elems.append(Spacer(1,12))
elems.append(Spacer(1,12))
elems.append(Spacer(1,12))

elems.append(Paragraph(nfattura_ptext, styles["Normal"]))
cliente_ptext = soggetto.nome+" "+soggetto.cognome+"<br/>"+soggetto.indirizzo+", "+soggetto.cap+" "+soggetto.citta+"<br/>C.F.: "+soggetto.codfisc
if(soggetto.is_privato):
    cliente_ptext += "P.IVA: "+soggetto.piva

prezzo = Prezzo.objects.get(pk=1)

prestazioni = []
if fattura.riabmot > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'Rieducazione motoria','qta': fattura.riabmot,'p_unit': prezzo.riabmot,
                        'p_finale': fattura.riabmot * prezzo.riabmot,'id':'riabmot'})
if fattura.riabacq > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'Riabilitazione in acqua','qta': fattura.riabacq,'p_unit': prezzo.riabacq,
                        'p_finale': fattura.riabacq * prezzo.riabacq,'id':'riabacq'})
if fattura.riabdom > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'Riabilitazione domiciliare','qta': fattura.riabdom,'p_unit': prezzo.riabdom,
                        'p_finale':fattura.riabdom * prezzo.riabdom,'id':'riabdom'})
if fattura.osteo > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'Osteopatia','qta': fattura.osteo,'p_unit': prezzo.osteo,
                        'p_finale':fattura.osteo * prezzo.osteo,'id':'osteo'})
if fattura.masso > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'Massoterapia','qta': fattura.masso,'p_unit': prezzo.masso,
                        'p_finale':fattura.masso * prezzo.masso,'id':'masso'})
if fattura.diate > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'Diatermia','qta': fattura.diate,'p_unit': prezzo.diate,
                             'p_finale':fattura.diate * prezzo.diate,'id':'diate'})
if fattura.laser > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'Laserterapia','qta': fattura.laser,'p_unit': prezzo.laser,
                            'p_finale':fattura.laser * prezzo.laser,'id':'laser'})
if fattura.usman > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'US Manuale','qta': fattura.usman,'p_unit': prezzo.usman,
                            'p_finale':fattura.usman * prezzo.usman,'id':'usman'})
if fattura.usacq > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'US in acqua','qta': fattura.usacq,'p_unit': prezzo.usacq,
                            'p_finale':fattura.usacq * prezzo.usacq,'id':'usacq'})
if fattura.tens > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'TENS','qta': fattura.tens,'p_unit': prezzo.tens,
                            'p_finale':fattura.tens * prezzo.tens,'id':'usacq'})
if fattura.ets > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'Elettroterapia stimolante','qta': fattura.ets,'p_unit': prezzo.ets,
                             'p_finale': fattura.ets * prezzo.ets,'id':'ets'})
if fattura.magneto > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'Magnetoterapia','qta': fattura.magneto,'p_unit': prezzo.magneto,
                            'p_finale':fattura.magneto * prezzo.magneto,'id':'magneto'})
if fattura.iono > 0:
    prestazioni.append({'nome':'Ionoforesi','qta': fattura.iono,'p_unit': prezzo.iono,
                            'p_finale':fattura.iono * prezzo.iono,'id':'iono'})

totale = 0
totale += fattura.diate * prezzo.diate
totale += fattura.ets * prezzo.ets
totale += fattura.iono * prezzo.iono
totale += fattura.tens * prezzo.tens
totale += fattura.laser * prezzo.laser
totale += fattura.magneto * prezzo.magneto
totale += fattura.masso * prezzo.masso
totale += fattura.usacq * prezzo.usacq
totale += fattura.usman * prezzo.usman
totale += fattura.osteo * prezzo.osteo
totale += fattura.riabacq * prezzo.riabacq
totale += fattura.riabdom * prezzo.riabdom
totale += fattura.riabmot * prezzo.riabmot

prestazioni_instestazione_ptext = "Prestazione     N.Sedute     Pr. unitario (euro)     Pr. finale (euro)"
elems.append(Paragraph(prestazioni_instestazione_ptext, normalStyle))
elems.append(Spacer(1,12))
for p in prestazioni:
    prestazione_ptext = str(p['nome']+"     "+str(p['qta'])+"     "+str(p['p_unit'])+"     "+str(p['p_finale']))
    print 'prestazione_ptext type : ',type(prestazione_ptext)
    elems.append(Paragraph(prestazione_ptext, styles["Normal"]))

elems.append(Spacer(1,12))
elems.append(Spacer(1,12))
totale_ptext = "Importo totale: "+str(totale)+" euro"
print 'totale_ptext: ',totale_ptext
elems.append(Paragraph(totale_ptext, styles["Normal"]))


f.addFromList(elems,p)
p.drawImage(static_files_dir_path+img_file,450,730,img_width,img_height)
p.save()
return buffer
```

but it still doesn't work. the issue seems to be on this section:

```
for p in prestazioni:
    prestazione_ptext = str(p['nome']+"     "+str(p['qta'])+"     "+str(p['p_unit'])+"     "+str(p['p_finale']))
    print 'prestazione_ptext type : ',type(prestazione_ptext)
    elems.append(Paragraph(prestazione_ptext, styles["Normal"]))
```

on which i got the following error:

*AttributeError at /fattura/pdf/
'dict' object has no attribute 'saveState'*

removing that section the code works. any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Platypus, you'll need to set up frames on the page.  Then you can specify what frame to put particular content into on the page.  In your case, it would be something like set up a frame to contain the image and then a frame to contain the content.  You can then build page templates out of frames and apply those page templates to particular pages as you generate them.  This is the general pattern for doing complex layout in ReportLab with Platypus.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to achive that. Looking at the current [source code](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab/src/b591b402f4cfe770d56b3f970630b42bf4a4ec4f/src/reportlab/platypus/flowables.py?at=default#cl-385), I have come up with the following solution:

```
from reportlab.platypus import Image

class AlignedImage(Image):
    def __init__(self, filename, hAlign='CENTER', **kwargs):
        Image.__init__(self, filename, **kwargs)
        self.hAlign = hAlign

# simply use it like this ('LEFT' can also be used):
my_image = AlignedImage('/foo/bar.png', hAlign='RIGHT')
```

All the required code is already here; I have [reported the issue](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab/issue/54/allow-to-specify-horizontal-alignment-to) to add this parameter directly in the Image class.

Answer (score 1):

looks to be there now!

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Image, HRFlowable

ss = reportlab.lib.styles.getSampleStyleSheet() 
p1 = Paragraph("Title", ss['Heading1'])                                                                    
p2 = Paragraph("normal paragraph", ss['BodyText'])                                                         
p3 = HRFlowable(width="100%")  
p4 = Image("/home/usr/Downloads/me.jpg", width=100, height=75, hAlign="LEFT")                  
        
flo = [p4,p3,p1,p3,p2]  
pdf = SimpleDocTemplate("test.pdf") 
pdf.showboundary = 1
pdf.build(flo)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.